# Date Format from common string

Tags: php

I have a date format but still on **String** like this :

```
$date = '24-01-2017' # (dd-mm-yy)
```

I want to display them into datetime in Indonesian format

```
Selasa, 24-01-2017
```

In english

```
Tuesday, 24-01-2017
```

So, I created like this :

```
$date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat(' j-M-Y', $date);
echo $date_format->date('d-M-Y')
```

Not works

Comment: What's your question  ?  you have error ?  .. yuor code is not enough for eval your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the `format()` function.

```
$now = new DateTime();
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');

 // or
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
```

Change the format to whatever you please.

To get the day in your own language:

```
$days = array(
    '0' => 'Mon day',
    '1' => 'Tues - Day',
    // ... etc
);
```

You can now do:

```
$day = $now->format('n');
echo $days[$day].', '.$now->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

From a [website](http://komputerbelajar.blogspot.com/2010/07/php-displaying-date-and-time-in.html) that I found by doing a search for '*Date Time in Indonesian format, php*'

> PHP : Displaying the date and time in indonesian language
>   By this time I hope you can create your own date and time using the timestamp
>   of the current date or your own timestamp.
>
> I use Indonesia language and I want to
>   display the date in Indonesian language. How can I do it? That's a perfect
>   question and asked by most beginners.
>
> #### Let's create an associative array of date and month in our own language.
>
> ```
> $days = Array ("Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jum'at", "Sabtu");
> $months = Array (1=>"Januari", 2=>"Pebruari", 3=>"Maret", 4=>"April",
> 5=>"Mei", 6=>"Juni", 7=>"Juli", 8=>"Agustus", 9=>"September",
> 10=>"Oktober", 11=>"Nopember", 12=>"Desember");
> ```
>
> #### After we create our own language of date and months, now it's time to display it.
>
> ```
> print $days[date("w")]; // display name of day with our own language
> print $months[date("n")];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From php.net :

> F and M : A textual representation of a month, such as January or Sept    January through December or Jan through Dec
>
> m and n : Numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros  01 through 12 or 1 through 12

You have to use "m" and not "M"

BTW, the method is not "date" but "format". ;)

```
<?php
$date = '24-01-2017';
$date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $date);
echo $date_format->format('D d-m-Y');
?>
```

This outputs :

```
Tue 24-01-2017
```